# Supremum of $A = \{ \frac{5^{3n}*5^{2m}}{3*5^{5n}+5^n + 2*5^{5m}} , n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

How do I find the supremum and infimum of set A?

$$A = \{ \frac{5^{3n}*5^{2m}}{3*5^{5n}+5^n + 2*5^{5m}} , n, m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

I know that this expression is always greater than 0 since it is made of natural numbers only.

- for $n = 1$, $m \implies \infty$, $A \implies 0$
- for $m = 1$, $n = \implies \infty$, $A \implies 0$

Therefore, I know that the infimum is equal to $0$. However, how do I find the supremum?

From a graph I made I know that for $n = m = 1$ that expression is equal to $\frac{1}{5}$ and that might be the supremum. However, how do I deduct that from this expression? I tried dividing nominator and denominator by $5^n$ and $5^m$. I tried comparing nominator to denominator. Got nothing.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: For $\,n=m=1\,$ the expression is $\,\frac{5^4}{5^5+1}\neq \frac15$.

Comment: You are right. It is near but never equal to $\frac{1}{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :** Let $x=5^n$ and $y=5^m$. Notice that

$$
\frac{1}{5}-\frac{x^3y^2}{3x^5+x+2y^5} =
\frac{1}{5(3x^5+x+2y^5)}\bigg(
x+(y-x)^2\big(3x^3 + 6yx^2 + 4y^2x + 2y^3\big)\bigg)
$$

Comment: Ok, but you begin your equation with $\frac{1}{5}$. And my question is - how to get $\frac{1}{5}$ at the end. Suppose that I can't graph the function and I need to just analyse that expression without any hint comming from picture. How would I get that idea?

Comment: A natural way to get that idea is as follows : when $n=1$, the max is attained for $m=1$, when $n=2$, the max is attained for $m=2$, etc. It is then natural to look at what happens when $m=n$ (or $x=y$ in my notation), and this is where the $\frac{1}{5}$ is obtained.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Now that makes sense. So I just observe first couple of cases. Thank you!